# jQuery.bind and .trigger without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I want to do the equivalent of this:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    myResizeFunction();
}).trigger('resize');
```

without jquery.

The reason being is. This is the only part of code in my javascript library that uses jquery.

And i see no point in including jquery if im only using this one command.

NOTE: Just to clarify, i want myResizeFunction to run everytime the broswer is resized. A cross-browser solution is prefered!

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this

```
<script>
var resizeMe = function() {
    myResizeFunction();
}

resizeMe();
</script>
```

To hook with resize event of window

```
window.onresize = resizeMe
```

Comment: but will this function be called every time the browser is resized?

Comment: No, this will called only when page is loaded. If you want to hook with resize see my edit

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour: There is a five minute grace period where edits to an answer do not show as a new revision. I wrote my answer before this answer contained the magical `window.onresize`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, jQuery is simply using [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize).

```
window.onresize = function() {
    //stuff
};
```

For your case:

```
window.onresize = myResizeFunction;
myResizeFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// binding event
if(window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener("resize",myResizeFunction,false);
else if(window.attachEvent)window.attachEvent("onresize",myResizeFunction);
// trigger event handler
myResizeFunction();
```

It's not full equivalent of jQuery `.bind` and `.trigger`, but it's valid main usage of `resize` event